# Counting number of files in a directory with Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

Using Apache Nifi, I am passing files to a directory. I want to count the number of files in this directory, wait until all of the files I need are present, and then run the StreamExecuteCommand processor to process the data in that directory. (Right now, the StreamExecute doesn't wait long enough for all of the files to arrive before the process begins - so I want to add this wait)

I just want to know how to count the number of files in a directory to start. I am using ListFiles to retrieve the names of files, but not sure how to count them in NiFi.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `ExecuteStreamCommand` to run a shell command on the files, you could easily add something like `ls -l | wc -l` to the same or additional `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor to count the number of files in the directory.

We usually caution against this approach, however, because there are edge cases where you can have a file present in the directory which isn't "complete" if some external process is writing it. The model usually recommended is to write files in with a temporary filename like `.file1`, `.file2`, and rename each upon successful completion to `file1`, `file2`, etc. The [`ListFile`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListFile/index.html) processor supports numerous settings to avoid detecting these files until they are ready for processing.

We also usually recommend setting some boolean flag through the external process rather than waiting for an explicit count unless that value will never change.